# Multithreading with classes

Tags: java, multithreading

This is a bit of an interesting question but I wanted to know everyone's thoughts on this design pattern.

```
public class MyThreadedMap {

     private ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Object> map;

     ...

     public class Wrapper {
          public Object get(int index){
               return map.get(index);
          }
     }
}
```

At this point multiple threads will have their own instance of Wrapper and would be accessing the map with wrapper.get(index).

I found that the performance change from having the wrapper and not having the wrapper is just slightly better, that is the wrapper helps a little. When I place synchronized on the get method there is a serious performance hit.

What exactly is happening here? When an inner class is instantiated am I creating a copy of that get method for each instance? Would it be best if I just left the wrapper out since there is no real performance gain?

Answer (score 1):

ConcurrentHashMap has fancy ways of minimizing synchronization overhead.  When you synchronize the get method, it imposes normal synchronization overhead, thus the performance hit.

If there is no other code in the Wrapper class, I would just leave it out as it doesn't appear to add anything.

Comment: That is true but for this example it's just a small light one to get the idea started. Let's now say there's a bunch of code shared between threads. Lot's of to-do code that work on that map or use the map. Would it make sense then or does Java do a pretty good job about shared methods between threads?

Comment: Methods are just code; they are always shared between threads, since they don't change in the course of execution of a program.  It's only data sharing between threads where one has to be careful.